# Reference Dockerfile from docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a web service that uses a MySQL as its backing store. I want to Dockerize this service as well as its MySQL DB. For the service I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as cce

COPY build/libs/my-service.jar my-service.jar

EXPOSE 9200

ENTRYPOINT [ \
    "java", \
    "-Ddb.hostAndPort=my-service-db:3306", \
    "-Ddb.name=my_service_db_local", \
    "-Ddb.username=my-service-user", \
    "-Ddb.password=abc123", \
    "-jar", \
    "my-service.jar" \
]
```

If I understand the Docker ecosystem correctly, it sounds like I can write a Docker Compose file to spin up the MySQL container instance as well as the web service container instance. So I have a `docker-compose.yml` file started that looks like so:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  my-service-db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: my-service-db
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: r00tdud3
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_service_db_local
      MYSQL_USER: my-service-user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: abc123
    volumes:
      - ./my-service-db-data:/var/lib/mysql
  my-service:
    ??? how to specify local Dockerfile here ???
    depends_on:
      - my-service-db
```

From my own tinkering I'm confident the MySQL container is configured the way I want it and correctly. Now I'm just trying to figure out how to tell `docker-compose.yml` file (which will live in the root directory of my project, right alongside the Dockerfile) to use the service's Dockerfile, and that it depends on the MySQL container first being started/running. I think I'm close but I'm having a hard time crossing the finish line.

Can anyone help me configure `docker-compose.yml` to create a service called `my-service` that uses the local `Dockerfile` for its config?

Comment: Tell it to [`build:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) the image.  (You probably do not want to hard-code configuration parameters like the database host name, and especially not credentials like the password; try passing them at deploy time as environment variables or using another mechanism.)

Comment: Why the DV? This question is on topic, is not a dupe, shows effort/research and provides succinct reproducible code examples. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an image from the dockerfile:

```
docker build - < Dockerfile
```

Then you should tag you image with a proper name.

After creating the image reference it in the docker-compose.yml file:

```
my-service: 
   image: ${image_name}
```

Another option is to simply write:

```
my-service: 
   build: .
```